# how to save image after connecting the two points through line?

Tags: matlab

I find the centroid of two blobs in an image and connected the theses centroid through-line. I want to save the image with the line, how may do it?

please complete the following Matlab code:

```
I = imread('C:\Data\uploaded_video\Static_Occlusion_frames_of_big_blob_Croped2\static_occ_id003_6\frame0062.jpg');
Ibw = im2bw(I);
Ibw = imfill(Ibw,'holes');
Ilabel = bwlabel(Ibw);
stat = regionprops(Ilabel,'centroid');   
figure,imshow(I);
hold on;
for x = 1: numel(stat)-1
    line([round(stat(x).Centroid(1)) round(stat(x+1).Centroid(1))],[round(stat(x).Centroid(2)) round(stat(x+1).Centroid(2))],'Color','w','LineWidth',1);
end
```

save image with line.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution of my question and edited the Matlab code as follow:

```
I = imread('C:\Data\uploaded_video\Static_Occlusion_frames_of_big_blob_Croped2\static_occ_id003_6\frame0062.jpg');
Ibw = im2bw(I);
Ibw = imfill(Ibw,'holes');
Ilabel = bwlabel(Ibw);
stat = regionprops(Ilabel,'centroid');
figure('visible', 'off'),imshow(I);
hold on;
for x = 1: numel(stat)-1
  line([round(stat(x).Centroid(1)) round(stat(x+1).Centroid(1))],[round(stat(x).Centroid(2)) round(stat(x+1).Centroid(2))],'Color','w','LineWidth',1);
end
hold off
F = getframe ;
% save the image:
imwrite(F.cdata, 'C:\Data\1.jpg')
close(figure)
```